# mongoDB user not found error while connecting from python code

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a local `mongoDB` server running and I created an `admin` user through this command:

```
db.createUser({user:"admin",pwd:"abc", roles:[{role:"root",db:"admin"}]})
```

I can also see following comming up in `mongoDB` shell when I execute `db.getUser('admin')`

```
{
        "_id" : "test.admin",
        "user" : "admin",
        "db" : "test",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
```

But when I try to connect to this `mongoDB` instance from my python code using below line I get following error: `I ACCESS   [conn5] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for admin on admin from client 127.0.0.1:51174 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user admin@admin`

```
host = os.environ.get('MONGO_HOST') or 'localhost'
port = os.environ.get('MONGO_PORT') or '27017'
username = os.environ.get('MONGO_USERNAME') or 'admin'
password = os.environ.get('MONGO_PASSWORD') or 'abc'
database = os.environ.get('MONGO_DB') or 'admin'
client = MongoClient('mongodb://'+username+':'+password+'@'+host+':'+str(port)+'/admin')
```

What is the mistake here and why is it throwing this error?

Comment: Try to set `authSource` explicitly: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html#default-database-and-authsource. As a side note, `admin` is a system db. Don't mess with it.

Comment: `"db" : "test",` says you actually created the user in the `test` database. Despite the incorrect advice from @AlexBlex, the general expectation is that you create users within the `admin` database. You can "work around this" by using `authSource` or indeed with the newer standard on ALL drivers is that the `database` on the end of the connection string is actually the "authentication database". Therefore just `/test` instead of `/admin` on the end of the URI fixes this. But you really should remove the user and create in the `admin` database space instead.

Comment: My *incorrect advice* was about connection string in the MongoClient parameter. There is no good reason to connect to admin database.